# Java: Move Directory containing files and directories to new path

Tags: java, file, unix

I have one directory containing some files and sub directory having more files in it.

```
Folder -  Directory (path -> /home/abc/xyz/Folder)
  ->Abc.txt  (file)
  -> Xyz.zip (file)
  -> Address (Sub Directory)
         -> PWZ.log (file)
         -> CyZ.xml (file)
  -> DataLog.7zip
```

etc

What I am trying to do is move this complete Directory from one path to another including all the files and subfolder(and their files).

ie Move this "Folder" from /home/abc/xyz/Folder to /home/abc/subdir/Folder.

Does Java provides any API to do this task based on FOLDER directory or do we need to do recursive copy each and every file only to this path?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best approach is probably a recursive method, like:
This is a method I created for moving files into a temp folder.

```
private boolean move(File sourceFile, File destFile)
{
    if (sourceFile.isDirectory())
    {
        for (File file : sourceFile.listFiles())
        {
            move(file, new File(file.getPath().substring("temp".length()+1)));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        try {
            Files.move(Paths.get(sourceFile.getPath()), Paths.get(destFile.getPath()), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why not use while loop instead; which has no limits. There is a limit to how many function calls can be made before returning. As each function call permits the OS to store state before entering the function

Answer (score 18):

You can simply move directory by using

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.*;

Files.move(new File("C:\\projects\\test").toPath(), new File("C:\\projects\\dirTest").toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Change source and destination path

Refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/move.html) to get more details

Also Note from API

```
 When invoked to move a
     * directory that is not empty then the directory is moved if it does not
     * require moving the entries in the directory.  For example, renaming a
     * directory on the same {@link FileStore} will usually not require moving
     * the entries in the directory. When moving a directory requires that its
     * entries be moved then this method fails (by throwing an {@code
     * IOException}). To move a <i>file tree</i> may involve copying rather
     * than moving directories and this can be done using the {@link
     * #copy copy} method in conjunction with the {@link
     * #walkFileTree Files.walkFileTree} utility method
```

If you try to move the file in the same partition , the above code is sufficient ( it can move directory even it has entries). if not ( instead of move) you need to use recursive as other answer mentioned.

Answer (score 9):

If you have imported [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) already anyways:

```
FileUtils.moveDirectory(oldDir, newDir);
```

Note that `newDir` must not exist beforehand. From the javadocs:

> ```
> public static void moveDirectory(File srcDir,
>                                  File destDir)
>                       throws IOException
> ```
>
> Moves a directory.
> When the destination directory is on another file system, do a "copy and delete".
>
> Parameters:
> srcDir - the directory to be moved
> destDir - the destination directory
>
> Throws:
> NullPointerException - if source or destination is null
> FileExistsException - if the destination directory exists
> IOException - if source or destination is invalid
> IOException - if an IO error occurs moving the file

Comment: Jsut note here, that apache commons have issues with soft symlinks. If they are broken, they will fail here. Considering they are trying to be as old-java-as-possible compatible, this is unlikely to change

Answer (score 7):

[`Files.move()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29) will work provided that the file system is able to "move" the file. This usually requires that you be moving to a different location on the same disk.

Answer (score 4):

```java
   private static void move(File sourceFile, File destFile) {
        if (sourceFile.isDirectory()) {
            File[] files = sourceFile.listFiles();
            assert files != null;
            for (File file : files) move(file, new File(destFile, file.getName()));
            if (!sourceFile.delete()) throw new RuntimeException();
        } else {
            if (!destFile.getParentFile().exists())
                if (!destFile.getParentFile().mkdirs()) throw new RuntimeException();
            if (!sourceFile.renameTo(destFile)) throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }
```

works for me

Answer (score 2):

Java has this built in, using native OS operation, in [File.renameTo(File dest)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo-java.io.File-).

Example:

```
new File("/home/alik/Downloads/src").renameTo(new File("/home/alik/Downloads/target"))
```

Comment: This failed for me (return false), but `FileUtils.moveDirectory` worked.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the `renameTo` method (already present in the `File` class from JDK) after you made sure the directories in the destination path are existing (e.g. by calling `mkdirs()`).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void move(File srcDir, File destDir) throws IOException {
    FileUtils.copyDirectory(srcDir, destDir, true);
    if(srcDir.isDirectory()) {
        for(File file: srcDir.listFiles()) {
            FileUtils.forceDelete(file);
        }
    }
}
```

FileUtils from package org.apache.commons.io;

Comment: FileUtils.deleteDirectory(srcDir) should do the delete job recursively