# Android moving a folder to another folder programmatically

Tags: android, directory

I want to know in Android how can I move a directory (a folder) not a file from a directory to another. How can I proceed, I used this function:

```
private void moveFile(String inputPath, String inputFile, String outputPath) {

    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        //create output directory if it doesn't exist
        File dir = new File (outputPath); 
        if (!dir.exists())
        {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }

        in = new FileInputStream(inputPath + inputFile);        
        out = new FileOutputStream(outputPath + inputFile);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        in.close();
        in = null;

        // write the output file
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = null;

        // delete the original file
        new File(inputPath + inputFile).delete();
    } 

    catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe1) {
        Log.e("tag", fnfe1.getMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I put the read-write permission, but it only moves files but not folders.

Comment: Do you want to move your folder into the same File System or into a different one?

Comment: Check the `File renameTo()` method. You can do it easily.

Comment: i want to move some folder in android phone storage in antother folder for exemple /storage/emulated/0/Music , i want to move it into /storage/emulated/0/Movie/file.  the hole folder i mean also the existing file in Music :) help

Comment: Did you try to use `dir.renameTo(new FIle("my/new/path"))` after creating your "dir" folder?

Comment: what is dir a predefined class or i have to declare it

Comment: what is the type of dir plz i try with inputstream and file and there is no function renameTo

Comment: According to your code, `dir` is a file that you created :D

Comment: oh yeah but it can't make the job because the two file must be on the same mount point :/

Comment: what i want to do is have the possibilty to move file and folder wherever i want in the storage

Comment: You mean from internal storage to SD card, for example?

Comment: FOR EXEMPLE this the folde that i want to move it "/storage/emulated/0/Movies"   the target folder  "/storage/emulated/0/Music/NOUVAU"    I Want to move Movies with the included file in it into NOUVAU :)

Comment: Those two paths are in the same mount point. You can do it with `renameTo()`

Comment: i did it with this manner and no result :(             File dir = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Movies/");
             File dir2 = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Music/Music/NOUVAU/");
             dir.renameTo(dir2);

Comment: You may not have permissions to write on that path. Did you try to add `getFilesDir()` to the beginning of your file path?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: Move Directory containing files and directories to new path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23346922/java-move-directory-containing-files-and-directories-to-new-path)

Comment: @Estevanbs That's not a great solution for Android, as it requires API level 26.