# How to change the name of a folder in Java

Tags: java, file

I would like to change the name of a directory.

I have the next piece of code:

```
Files.move(dir.toPath(), newDir.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

but I get this error when I execute the code, the next exception is returned.

```
java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: C:\ws\dir -> C:\ws\aux
```

I have checked that the folder *C:\ws\newDir* doesn't exists and *C:\ws\dir* does.

I have also tried `File.renameTo()` but it doesn't work with folders.

Comment: Apparently the problem is related with the new name of the directory `aux`. When I changed the name it started working.

Comment: In that case, I would add some code to check the existence of dest folder before I make my move.

Comment: I checked the folder and it didn't exist. It was a very strange issue. Anyway, the problem is solved since the final name it is not important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on this [official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/move.html)

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.*;
...
Files.move(source, target, REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Should works for you.

You could also use other copy options for the 3rd parameter.

For checking existence of File or Folder, checkout this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/check.html)

Checkout this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23346962/411604).

BTW, make sure you have the right permission to move Dir/File, and you only **move once**.

Comment: I have updated the question adding the third parameter. It doesn't work and the destiny folder doesn't exist.

Comment: Apparently the issue was related with the name of the file. I am accepting your answer because it is accurate in other cases. Thank you!